# Getting repeats of output, possibly doing a join wrong?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having an issue where I'm getting some incorrect values in my output. I am binding the below highlighted table column with the circled column down the bottom. The service_id on the highlighted column is what is unique, but I need to bind the booking_id to retrieve the info (if that makes sense. What I end up getting is the top table where I get repeats, or the price is wrong. I should be getting only 5 lines in the top table.

[image]

Here's my code. I suspect I might be doing the join wrong?

```
SELECT bad.agent as Agents,
dog.SUPPLIER as SUPPLIER,
bad.status as TheStatus,
country.analysis_master1 as Country,
ftb.booking_actual_retail as BookingActualRetail,
ftb.Booking_Actual_Cost as BookingCost,
ftb.Booking_Actual_Retail_inc as BookingRetailINC,
fts.Service_Id,
fts.Service_Actual_Retail_inc as ServiceActualCostInc,
Product.SERVICE,
Product.SL_STATUS as SLSTATUS,
cat.name as Product2,
bad.LAST_SERVICE_DATE as Servicedate,
bad.LW_DATE as LWDATE,
ftb.Entered_Date as DATEENTERED,
ftb.Booking_Pax as PEOPLE,
ftb.Booking_Children as KIDS,
bad.TRAVELDATE as TRAVELDATE,
bad.FULL_REFERENCE
from BHD bad
inner join FTB on bad.FULL_REFERENCE = ftb.booking_reference
inner join FTS on FTB.Booking_Id = fts.Booking_Id
inner join DRM Country on bad.agent = country.code
inner join BSL Product on bad.BHD_ID = Product.BHD_ID
inner join SRV cat on Product.SERVICE = cat.CODE
inner join OPT dog on Product.OPT_ID = dog.OPT_ID
where bad.STATUS = 'IV' AND bad.FULL_REFERENCE = 'LTIT129488'
```

UPDATE:

Ok, so it looks like this join here causes the multiple outputs:

```
inner join FTS on FTB.Booking_Id = fts.Booking_Id
```

I have included the two tables, their headers, and sample data

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you join multiple tables, you get **multiple** matching rows according to the join predicates. Since you are joining 7 tables, you are probably producing a ton of matching rows and that compounds in a big result set.

Comment: Sample data and expected results will go a long way for us to understand your case, so we can help you out.

Comment: The image above is exactly that. I would be expecting to get the middle table in the above graphic, five lines. The top table is what I get.

Comment: As far as I can tell you have 5 records in the table `FTB` for this booking reference ('LTIT129488'), and a further 5 in `FTS`. Hence the 25 different combinations. If you only want one record to be returned from each table, you will need to supply some logic as to how to chose this one record from the 5 available. Or if there are further relations to relate the 5 rows in each table, then you need to add this to your join logic. Without knowing what your tables are, or how they link together this is pretty hard to answer.

Comment: Alright, I will amend a little more

Comment: GarethD I have added some more info

Answer (score 1):

You have somewhere put the join for the service or supplier in the wrong way.. Please check this line again.

```
inner join SRV cat on Product.SERVICE = cat.CODE
```

[image: as per the screenshot you have provided see the multiple service acreoss the same product]

UPDATED SOLUTION :

As per your updated screenshots, I found the issue...
you have joined like this.

```
    inner join FTB on bad.FULL_REFERENCE = ftb.booking_reference
```

In this join, your one table has single record against booking reference while another have multiple records against booking refrence. Thats why you are getting the multiple records in the output.

[image]

Remove this join and your problem will be solved. If you really want the data from this table then you can select in other way like using outer apply etc.

Comment: would you recommend using a different join? Or are you saying I should join a different column?

Comment: I would recommend to join on a different column. Inner join is ok.

Comment: gotcha, will try

Comment: Hey, does what I've provided help more?

Comment: Yes, checkout the updated solution. If it use useful, please upvote.